# Rで2列の内容を1列に結合する方法

Tags: r

Rのビギナーの質問で恐縮です。

NAが含まれている2列のデータの内容を、1列にまとめて出力する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

**元になるデータ:**

|  | A家 | B家 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 自転車 | 1 | NA |
| バイク | NA | 2 |
| 車 | 1 | NA |
| その他 | NA | 2 |

**出力したいもの:**

|  | 合計 |
| --- | --- |
| 自転車 | 1 |
| バイク | 2 |
| 車 | 1 |
| その他 | 2 |

これまで試した方法ですが、`left_join(A列,B列)` を使ったところ、エラーが出ている状況です。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
クラス "c('integer', 'numeric')" のオブジェクトに適用できるようなメソッドがありません
```

解決を試みて、NANを0など別の数値に置き換える、1をintegerからnumericにするなどを試しましたが、いずれでも同様のエラーが出ました。

どなたかお助けくださるかた、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowSums()` を使います。その際、`NA` を除外するために `na.rm=TRUE` を指定します。

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "製品" = c("自転車", "バイク", "車", "その他"),
  "A家" = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
  "B家" = c(NA, 2, NA, 2)
)

dfn <- data.frame(
  "製品" = df["製品"],
  "合計" = rowSums(df[,c("A家", "B家")], na.rm=TRUE)
)
print(dfn)

## 出力結果

    製品 合計
1 自転車    1
2 バイク    2
3    車    1
4 その他    2
```

Answer (score 0):

tidyverseを使うと、もう少し直感的な書き方が出来ます。

```
df %>%
  mutate(合計 = rowSums(.[2:3], na.rm = TRUE))
```